# PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials always returns false for an account with mixed-case user name

Tags: c#, active-directory, account-management

I got two domain user accounts. One has a lower-case user name and another one has mixed-case user name, like "JohnSmith".
ValidateCredentials works fine for the lower-case user name. However, for the mixed-case user name it always returns false.

```
PrincipalContext myDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain");
bool loginSucceded = myDomain.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
```

I can use the following code to see the properties of both accounts (both are enabled). The property LastBadPasswordAttempt suggests that ValidateCredentials returns false not because of wrong password.

```
PrincipalContext myDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain");
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(myDomain, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);
if (user != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + user.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("DisplayName: " + user.DisplayName);
    Console.WriteLine("BadLogonCount: " + user.BadLogonCount);
    Console.WriteLine("Enabled: " + user.Enabled);
    Console.WriteLine("LastLogon: " + user.LastLogon);
    Console.WriteLine("LastBadPasswordAttempt: " + user.LastBadPasswordAttempt);
}
```

Passing the mixed-case user name converted to lower case did not help either.

UPD: responting to kyndigs' comment, it's a part of investigating an issue in an application that uses ValidateCredentials. Several users reported that they can't login and those users have mixed-case user names.

Comment: Has the password expired?

Comment: It has not, according to the info from IADsUser.

Comment: I dont think this is an issue with the case of the username, can you give me the values for the following in the UserPrincipal: AccountExpirationDate, AccountLockoutTime, DisplayName.

Comment: AccountExpirationDate is null; AccountLockoutTime is null; DisplayName is "MixedTest"

Comment: How are those values retrieved from the database?

Comment: @Silvermind: they are retrieved from AD, not from a database. See the second code snippet: AccountExpirationDate and AccountLockoutTime are properties of the UserPrincipal object as well.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked it.